How to order by a key of an object in an array?
with
p as (
  select p.*
  from products as p
  order by p.created_at desc
)

select
  c.*
  coalesce(p.products, '[]'::jsonb) as products
from categories as c
left join lateral (
  select jsonb_agg(p.*) as products
  from p
  where p.category_id = c.id
) as p on true
order by p.products->>'created_at' desc

How do I order by the created_at column of products in this query? I want to show categories with the most recently created products first.

p.products is a JSONB array so p.products->>'created_at' does not make much sense. Maybe you want to order the array itself? Or the result record by the latest created_at in the array?

The array is ordered in the CTE. I can order by the first object in the array but how do I get the created_at of that object?

Two remarks. (1) Ordering the CTE does not guarantee ordering of the array. Move order by p.created_at desc into the jsonb_agg brackets; (2) Use p.products->0->>'created_at' to get the created_at value of the first array element as text.

Regarding first remark, if I change the order by in the CTE to asc the array is reordered properly. Is there somewhere in a documentation that says ordering CTE does not guarantee ordering of array? Regarding remarking #2, it worked, given that the CTE does guarantee the order.

As a general rule the order of rows in a query result is undefined unless there is an explicit order by clause. There is no such thing as table (or CTE) rows' "natural" order. The results may be usually correct but this may (and will) unexpectedly fail in the worst moment possible.

The documentation may not state that ordering a CTE doesn't guarantee the array order; however, it also doesn't state that it does. Unspecified behavior is exactly that, unspecified; i.e., not guaranteed. Just because it appears to work in all of the cases you've tried, that doesn't mean that it will always work. Don't rely on unspecified behavior.

I agree. But in my case, I've tried multiple different order by (eg. name, created_at, updated_at, etc.) and they all worked.

Since the original post lacks DDL and sample data, I'll set up a demonstration environment with the following:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS categories (
  id BIGINT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  category_name TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  created_at TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT CLOCK_TIMESTAMP()
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products (
  id BIGINT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  product_name TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  category_id BIGINT REFERENCES categories(id),
  created_at TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT CLOCK_TIMESTAMP()
);

INSERT INTO categories(category_name)
SELECT 'CAT ' || s.n
  FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1,3) s(n);

INSERT INTO products (product_name, category_id)
SELECT 'PROD ' || ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY c.id, s.n) AS product_name, c.id
  FROM categories c
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL GENERATE_SERIES(2,c.id) s(n);

The following queries take advantage of the ability to reference ungrouped columns that are functionally dependent on the grouped columns. All columns in categories are dependent on id; therefore, the reference to c.* is permitted. The use of * in the select list is generally discouraged; however, I've retained it to be consistent with the original post. It would be better to explicitly enumerate the columns.
The first approach creates a JSONB array of each category's products sorted in descending product creation order. The query results are sorted by the created_at of first element of each category's product:
WITH cat_prods AS
  (SELECT c.*,
          COALESCE(JSONB_AGG(p.* ORDER BY p.created_at DESC) FILTER (WHERE p.id IS NOT NULL), '[]'::JSONB) AS products
     FROM categories c
     LEFT JOIN products p
       ON p.category_id = c.id
     GROUP BY c.id)
  SELECT cp.*
    FROM cat_prods cp
    ORDER BY (cp.products[0] ->> 'created_at')::TIMESTAMPTZ DESC NULLS LAST, cp.id;

Running this query produced the following results:



id
category_name
created_at
products




1
CAT 1
2024-06-22 15:41:47.709527-04
[]


2
CAT 2
2024-06-22 15:41:47.709812-04
[{"id": 1, "created_at": "2024-06-22T15:41:47.710021-04:00", "category_id": 2, "product_name": "PROD 1"}]


3
CAT 3
2024-06-22 15:41:47.709823-04
[{"id": 3, "created_at": "2024-06-22T15:41:47.710281-04:00", "category_id": 3, "product_name": "PROD 3"}, {"id": 2, "created_at": "2024-06-22T15:41:47.710272-04:00", "category_id": 3, "product_name": "PROD 2"}]



An alternative approach, which doesn't depend on the order of products in the JSONB array, uses a separate column to sort by the maximum product creation date of each category's products.
SELECT c.*,
       COALESCE(JSONB_AGG(p.*) FILTER (WHERE p.id IS NOT NULL), '[]'::JSONB) AS products,
       MAX(p.created_at) AS most_recent_product_created_at
  FROM categories c
  LEFT JOIN products p
    ON p.category_id = c.id
  GROUP BY c.id
  ORDER BY most_recent_product_created_at DESC NULLS LAST, c.id;

